# PHP - SQL query to get update time from table status

Tags: php, wordpress, mysql

This is my php code (I already have a connection to the db):

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM mydb LIKE 'mytable';");
     while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          $updatetime = $array['Update_time'];
     }

echo $updatetime;
```

I get:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource.

I am running MySQL 5.0.89 and PHP5.

I do not want to add a new field to the table... I want to use the table status...

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Not sure if this is the perfect way, but it works...

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM mydb LIKE 'mytable';");
foreach ($result as $data) {
    $updatetime = $data->Update_time;
}

echo $updatetime;
```

You can then parse the raw timestamp with substr.

P.S. As I was doing this for Wordpress, I am including the code specifically for working in the Wordpress DB...

```
global $wpdb;
define('FOO_TABLE', $table_prefix."footable");

$result = $wpdb->get_results("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE '".FOO_TABLE."';");
foreach ($result as $data) {
  $updatetime = $data->Update_time;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource.

You did not supply the *right* resource to `mysql_fetch_array`. Also, I believe you have your `$array` and `$result` variables mixed up, and note the `my_database` reference which I'll explain below.

```
$array = mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM my_database;"); <--here
     while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { <--$result is undefined.
```

Should be instead

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM my_database;");
     while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          $updatetime = $array['Update_time'];
     }

echo $updatetime;
```

As of now, your MySQL syntax is not correct in regards to [`SHOW TABLE STATUS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html) you need to reference your database after your `FROM` clause.

Comment: I was retyping it instead of copy/paste, but I do have it the way you pointed it out here.  Same result.

Comment: Could you edit your question and post the code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

The [show table status](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html) from should be followed by database name not table name:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM <DATABASE NAME>
```

Also every time you execute a query, you should always check its return value before you go ahead and start using the result object.

```
$res= mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM DB;");
if(! $res) {
 die('Query failed'.mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Table update time must be taken from table field **only**.